# How to install mhddfs on Synology

Tags: shared-directory, synology, mount-point

I want to have the HDDs in the NAS as separate volumes (to not loose all data when a single HDD fails; I don't need any protection like RAID; on the other hand, with JBOD or SHR I would loose data from all HDDs when only one fails). It means that they are mounted as separate devices into separate mount points. However, I want to share all the data as a single shared folder.

The only solution I found is mhddfs package which I have been using on a normal linux machine for a long time. However, how can I get it into the Synology NAS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partially based on [this forum](http://www.synology-forum.de/archive/index.html/t-37335.html), the setup is as follows (for DS216j, DSM 6.1.1):

1. Get the `mhddfs` binary for ARMv7 [from here](http://tardis.tiny-vps.com/aarm/packages/m/mhddfs/), e.g. [this version](http://tardis.tiny-vps.com/aarm/packages/m/mhddfs/mhddfs-0.1.39-2-armv7h.pkg.tar.xz).
2. Untar the file and copy the content of the archive into corresponding locations.
3. Now, you can use the `mhddfs` binary to mount the devices as necessary but it is still needed to setup the mount at the NAS boot.
4. Create a directory for the shared mount point, e.g. `/mnt/share`.
5. Create a script called e.g. `startup.sh` somewhere with the following content:

```
#!/bin/sh -e

# Create the mount point (only if it doesn't exist) - it may be deleted after DSM update
mkdir -p /mnt/share

#export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib
mhddfs /volume1/volume1,/volume2/volume2 /mnt/share -o logfile=/tmp/mhddfs.log -o allow_other

exit 0
```

6. Create a task in the DSM Task scheduler - to launch this script at boot.
7. Reboot.